# Meaning of my question

Tags: meaning

What does it mean when your stepdaughter puts a picture of herself and her boyfriend and I wish them the best and her reply is  thank you but my happiness is you and my dad

Answer (score 1):

Your stepdaughter wants to tell you that even though she is happy with her boyfriend, she is already happy because of her relationship with you and that with her father.